# Amazon SES bcc not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I have setup Amazon SES for a codeigniter based project, but it seem like all the bcc email is not delivered .. , I tested on the perl script that amazon provided , the bcc email also not received.

anyone out there using the SES service having the same problem ?

Comment: Answer is posted here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794401/aws-ses-sendrawemailasync-not-entertaining-bcc/38808187#38808187>

Comment: I have made it work, please see my post at [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794401/aws-ses-sendrawemailasync-not-entertaining-bcc)

Comment: I just made it work, please see post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794401/aws-ses-sendrawemailasync-not-entertaining-bcc

Answer (score 6):

Just find out is the gmail issue , when it wont send duplicate email to the same account.

Comment: I get this error when i try to use BCC. Warning: SimpleEmailService::sendEmail(): M M in ses.php on line 357

Comment: OMG, I was trying to figure out since hours what's wrong with our bcc code, only to find out it was exactly this gmail issue. Thanks @Knight.

Comment: Note that this will be the case even if you use the gmail "+ trick" to have multiple addresses.